# Why does sediment gather only at the centre of miso soup?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

This is a phenomenon I've noticed quite a few times when eating, and thought it interesting enough to be asked here. I am not sure, however, if a similar question has been posed before.

When I set a hot bowl of miso soup to cool on the table, I noticed that the sediments (probably micro-particles that make up the paste, although this phenomenon isn't specific just to miso paste) form a cloud-like blob at the centre. I tried the same thing with soup that has already been cooled, and do not notice the same effect.

Why do they gather at the centre instead of settling to the bottom when the soup is originally hot? I am guessing apart from temperature, the shape of the bowl (which is made of porcelain in this case) also plays a role, but I have not tested out my hypothesis yet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It has nothing to do with miso soup. All sediments in liquids do this. It has to do with the density and the type of rotation.

Comment: The soup wasn't stirred in this case though. I observed the same effect regardless whether I stirred it or not.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. When you scoup into a bowl, that is sufficient stirring to get things into that form.

Answer (score 1):

A hypothesis to evaluate, from another miso soup observer: [Convection cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection_cell) develop between the liquid at the cooler walls and at the as-yet-uncooled center. Some sediment rises in the cell, but the general trend is up, out, down, and inward. At the bottom of the cup, where the sediment concentration is expected to be highest from settling, the motion of the liquid is toward the center, collecting material there.